# MYSQL deleting duplicate values from a table that fall on a particular date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, inner-join

I have mysql table with three fields and additional `id` column which is `primary key`

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1.abc.com   10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-12-19 21:56:46
server2           11.1.1.1      2011-12-18 21:56:46
server2.abc.com   11.1.1.1      2011-12-17 21:56:46

Here,
host --> varchar
ipaddress --> varchar
date ---> datetime
```

I want to select `host` in the table which have duplicate entries for `ip`
I only want to check duplicate entry for host only if `date like '2011-12-19%'`

From above table, my result should satisfy condition `date like '2011-12-19%'`

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1.abc.com   10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-12-19 21:56:46
```

I have the following query which is working fine

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select ipaddress
      from tablename
      group by ipaddress
      having count(*) >= 2
         and count(case when CAST(date AS DATE) = '2017-12-19' then 1 end) > 0) t2
  on t1.ipaddress = t2.ipaddress
```

Now, I need help to write query to delete the row where `date NOT like '2011-12-19%'`
So, my table should have one entry for `ipaddress` which has `date like '2011-12-19%'`.

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1           10.1.1.1      2011-12-19 21:56:46
```

I have removed the entry for `date -> 2011-10-18 22:45:16` This way there wont be duplicate `ipaddress` in the table for which `date like '2011-12-19%'`

Comment: Question, is that all the fields there are? or is there another column that you use as the primary key?

Comment: there is an `id` column which is a primary key. Updated question as well

Comment: Another Question, how is `server1.abc.com   10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16` in the example satisfy `date like '2011-12-19%' ?`

Comment: It satisfies `date NOT like '2011-12-19%'` Here date is actually `server_createdate` I want to delete duplicate ip entry from the table where `date NOT like '2011-12-19%'`

Comment: I've created a sample sqlfiddle based on your example, and here's the result, please review and edit your code to reflect what is wrong with it, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c34dd/2/0

Comment: nevermind, your example is using 2017, it should be 2011

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DELETE` with `JOIN`:

```
delete t1
from mytable t1
join (select ipaddress
      from mytable
      group by ipaddress
      having count(*) >= 2
         and count(case when CAST(date AS DATE) = '2011-12-19' then 1 end) > 0) t2
  on t1.ipaddress = t2.ipaddress
where CAST(date AS DATE) != '2011-12-19'
```

Using this query you can delete record

```
host              ipaddress      date
----              ---------      -----
server1.abc.com   10.1.1.1      2011-10-18 22:45:16
```

from your table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbb7f7/1)

Comment: welp, guess you beat me to it xD